# How to use OR queries in greenDAO?

Tags: java, android, greendao

I have a query like:

```
Select * from table where user = 'user1' or city = 'delhi';
```

I know how to do it for single user but I am not getting how can I use `or` in following query.

```
dao.queryBuilder()
    .where(UserDao.Properties.UserId.eq(userId1))
    .list();
```

Comment: Please rephrase what are you asking about, because i have prediction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Version 3.2.+, here is an example to use a combination of `Where()` and `WhereOr()` conditions. The below is a hypothetical query to select all items:

1. That have the tags 'paint', 'emulsion'
2. That belong to a specific Category
3. Excluding a particular Sub Category

The `Where()` method takes exactly one query condition and the `WhereOr()` can take multiple query conditions (as many as the number of properties in the Dao Class), separated by comma

```
String catgId = "AB12545";
String excludeSubCatgId = "SAB09990";
DaoSession daoSession = ((App) getApplication()).getDaoSession();

List<Item> = daoSession.getItemDao().queryBuilder()
        .where(ItemDao.Properties.CategoryId.eq(catgId))
        .where(ItemDao.Properties.SubCategory.notEq(excludeSubCatgId))
        .whereOr(ItemDao.Properties.ItemTagCloud.like("%paint%"),
                 ItemDao.Properties.ItemTagCloud.like("%emulsion%"))
        .orderDesc(ItemDao.Properties.ItemPrice)
        .list();
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `or` conditions in greenDAO, you have to use `or` method in QueryBuilder object.
Example:

```
QueryBuilder<User> qb = dao.queryBuilder();
qb.where(UserDao.Properties.UserId.eq(userId1), qb.or(UserDao.Properties.City.eq("delhi")));
List<User> users = qb.list();
```

For more details, see the ["Queries" section](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/queries/) in greenDAO documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
QueryBuilder<User> qb = dao.queryBuilder();
qb.whereOr(UserDao.Properties.UserId.eq(userId1), 
UserDao.Properties.City.eq("delhi"));
List<User> users = qb.list();
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: This answer is for those using greenDao3, things have changed a little bit from the previous top answers...